# How to define regions in PDFTextStripperByArea?

Tags: java, apache, pdf, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox to extract text from PDF files. One problem I am facing is: PDFBox mixed the main content up with the PDF footer/header sections which I want to ignore.

I am told that the following code would help:

```
Rectangle rec = new Rectangle();
# init rec...
PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
stripper.addRegion("cropbox", rec); 
stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
```

Could anybody tell me what does `stripper.setSortByPosition(true)` exactly mean? I read the documentation but I am still confused:

And when I use the above code to extract text from PDF files, I got the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Comparison method violates its general contract!
at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:747)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:483)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:408)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:214)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:217)
at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.writePage(PDFTextStripper.java:565)
at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripperByArea.writePage(PDFTextStripperByArea.java:190)
at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.processPage(PDFTextStripper.java:457)
at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripperByArea.extractRegions(PDFTextStripperByArea.java:153)
```

Could anybody fix this for me?

PS: For your reference, here is the documentation of `setSortByPosition`:

The order of the text tokens in a PDF file may not be in the same as they appear visually on the screen. For example, a PDF writer may write out all text by font, so all bold or larger text, then make a second pass and write out the normal text.

The default is to not sort by position.

A PDF writer could choose to write each character in a different order. By default PDFBox does not sort the text tokens before processing them due to performance reasons.

PPS:
@Tilman Hausherr: This is a known problem :-(

See: issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1512

Update:
One possible way[1] to avoid these exceptions is:

```
System.setProperty("java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort", "true");
```

[1] [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1512?focusedCommentId=13937402&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13937402](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1512?focusedCommentId=13937402&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-13937402)

Comment: It will be fixed in version 1.8.8 (likely this year)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look into the source code and found out that their `TextPositionComparator` (`Comparator` used for sorting the text positions) seems to violate the contract. (TimSort [java 7+] may throw a exception in this case; PDFBox still seems to be compatible with java 4 and they plan to update to java 6 for version 2.0 so they may not be up to date...)

You best inform the developers ([PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/mailinglists.html)) of the bug. However you can download the source code and change the comparator yourself. I'm pretty sure the error is in line 63 (Revision 1575836) of the [`TextPositionComparator`](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/text/TextPositionComparator.java?view=markup).

There they allow some tolerance in the y value. You can come up with TextPositions that violate a part of the contract of the `Comparator` interface:

*The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: ((compare(x, y)>0) && (compare(y, z)>0)) implies compare(x, z)>0.*

**To show a violation of the condition is possible:** Choose `TextPosition.getYDirAdj()` (posYBottom) to be 0, 0.05 and 0.11 and make sure that conditions in lines 64, 65 are false and you can choose 1 of the 3 `compare` results by choosing the x positions the right way.

Comment: An update on this from the future: This error is no longer raised in PDFBox because they switched to their own quicksort algorithm, which is effectively the same as setting 'useLegacyMergeSort' but using that in PDFBox would have the downside of affecting other sorts that probably do want to perform those checks. The comparator is the same as it's always been. There's more discussion on this here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1512

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to the `Collections.sort(List<E> list)` method, which has been replaced with the JDK7. For furter informations look 
[here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#source):

> Area: API: Utilities Synopsis: Updated sort behavior for Arrays and
>   Collections may throw an IllegalArgumentException Description: The
>   sorting algorithm used by java.util.Arrays.sort and (indirectly) by
>   java.util.Collections.sort has been replaced. The new sort
>   implementation may throw an IllegalArgumentException if it detects a
>   Comparable that violates the Comparable contract. The previous
>   implementation silently ignored such a situation. If the previous
>   behavior is desired, you can use the new system property,
>   java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort, to restore previous mergesort
>   behavior. Nature of Incompatibility: behavioral RFE: 6804124

To fix the problem use that code:

```
System.setProperty("java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort", "true");
```

This will set the sort algorithm to the behavior before JDK7. Worked perfectly for me ...

Comment: This is correct, however see the comment by Uwe in PDFBOX-1512: "The problem with the workaround is that it needs to be done outside the application". Anyway, it will be solved in the upcoming version 1.8.8 :-)

Comment: thats good news! When will it be released? Only for your interest: i used a 25 book sample and there were only few pages where the problem ocurred. **ALL** pages where the problem ocurred were pages with: figures, tables, diagrams or mathematical formulas (simple text pages didn't invoke problems for me).

Answer (score 0):

Q: Could anybody tell me what does stripper.setSortByPosition(true) exactly mean?

A: My understanding of the PDF format is that it consists of characters (talking about the text here only) placed precisely using coordinates in relation to the bottom-left corner of the page. These characters when the PDF was authored where not necessarily inserted in one uninterrupted sequence inserting them left to right, top to bottom. So by setting SortByPosition to true you are telling PdfBox to attempt to order the characters using the order how would the characters appear on the screen versus the order of the characters in the PDF file.